# Sum of Multiple rows in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have data in this manner

```
ID       SUB       Marks    
 1      English      25
 1       Maths       22
 1      Science      15
 2      English      16
 2       Maths       20
 2      Science      12
```

And so on...

How would I sum all subject marks and give total marks of each ID?

For example, if I select ID=1 then it should show 62.

Comment: There are SQL manuals online if you don't actually want to buy one or take some training, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Visit this site and then come back and ask questions if you still can't work these things out.

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Marks) as totalMarks
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select id, sum(Marks) as marks
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this... this is working...

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Marks) as Total
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```